# Python Scheduling (difference in seconds)

Tags: python, datetime, scheduling

Python Noob. Would like to explore some details on python scheduling. As noticed the schedule has difference in seconds(each time it run).

How to make sure the schedule job runs at 5min interval with 00 seconds. i.e., <00:05:00>

My sample code is following:

```
while True:
if datetime.now().minute % 5 == 0: 
    #do something
    print(f'Date : {datetime.now()}')
time.sleep(60)
```

Current result:

> Date : 2022-06-06 13:00:09.513017
>
> Date : 2022-06-06 13:05:09.536887
>
> Date : 2022-06-06 13:10:09.590000
>
> Date : 2022-06-06 13:15:09.616859
>
> Date : 2022-06-06 13:20:09.663668
>
> Date : 2022-06-06 13:25:09.701900
>
> Date : 2022-06-06 13:30:09.732448
>
> Date : 2022-06-06 13:35:09.766074
>
> Date : 2022-06-06 13:40:09.797849
>
> Date : 2022-06-06 13:45:09.830098
>
> Date : 2022-06-06 13:50:09.859578
>
> Date : 2022-06-06 13:55:09.889196
>
> Date : 2022-06-06 14:00:09.922575
>
> Date : 2022-06-06 14:05:09.968444
>
> Date : 2022-06-06 14:10:10.007531
>
> Date : 2022-06-06 14:15:10.035127
>
> Date : 2022-06-06 14:20:10.082590
>
> Date : 2022-06-06 14:25:10.117690
>
> Date : 2022-06-06 14:30:10.170962

Can notice the difference in seconds it keep incrementing. Is there a better way to do ? so the code execute at 05-min with 00 seconds?

Comment: Usually it's easier to have an outside program execute the Python code on a schedule, like `cron`. Is that an option for you?

Comment: cron is solution but it need Linux, but my application is windows based exe file medical use. It need to schedule to run job every specific time of minute (cannot expect delay in seconds).